# Verb tense after someone died

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

Let's say I had a friend that **died**.

- When talking about him,
  should I now say:

  > I am his friend

  or

  > I was his friend
- What about marriage?

  Should the wife say:

  > I am his wife

  or

  > I was his wife
- And when using the verb *to know*, can I say

  > I know him

  after this person died?

Comment: While it is true that the general rule is to use the past tense, some people use the present tense when referring to the deceased.  Spiritualists who are trying to convey the enduring nature of the human spirit will often use the present tense when referring to the deceased.  In similar fashion people who are grieving will sometimes refer to the deceased in the present tense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56471/what-tense-to-use-for-a-dead-persons-permanent-contributions

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/108057/talking-about-late-husband

Comment: Voting to close on the grounds that this question is a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grammar and dead relatives](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/229808/grammar-and-dead-relatives)

Comment: An interesting passage: [*I'm his friend. I was his friend at six, I'm his friend now and I'll be his friend at eighty. It's just the way it is.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=b5m8CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT141) (Both friends seem to be alive.)

Answer (score 2):

You should say what you mean. In English, the question is not a question of idiom, but of plain, literal meaning.

The sentences would be understood either way, in their literal senses.

Now, culturally in English-speaking countries, it is usual to speak of the dead in the past tense.  So, "I was his friend," would be the more usual.

A Mormon might say, "I am his wife," because that is literally what she means. Most others would probably say, "I was his wife"—although widows are granted free discretion in this.  If she (being non-Mormon) says, "I am his wife," it means that she wishes to be regarded (in the context in which she is speaking) no differently than any married woman would be regarded: she does not wish to discuss her lack of a living husband.  If she says, "I was his wife," then she can politely, specifically be treated as a widow.

All this is culturally conventional.

So, the meanings are quite literal; but there will be a cultural context.